# How to get common friends of multiple facebook users?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of about 35 facebook user IDs. I want to use the facebook API to generate a list of users that are friends with everyone on my list.

I am friends with everyone on the list.

Is this possible to do with this [API Explorer Tool?](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to do this. Your best best is to choose one of them as the center. Find the mutual friends that A (the center) has with B. Now find what A has with C. Toss the ones that don't fit. Now find what A has with D. Toss. Find. Repeat.

You should batch these calls together to save resources.